# I am keep getting not found error on the POST /api/submit using flask-oauthlib library

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, reddit, flask-oauthlib

I am using flask oauthlib library . I am successfully getting get request however when I am trying update using post , I am getting back 404 not found error 
I am following the standard example they gave on the git page 
https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/example/reddit.py

I am making post request by (continuing the example of the git page)

```
body = {
    'kind' :  'self', 
    'sr'    : 'dev_playspace', 
    'title' :  "test playspace", 
    'text' : 'test text'
}
response = reddit.post('submit' , data=body); 

return jsonify({'response' :  response.data})
```

I have logged what library is actually sending. 
url : https://oauth.reddit.com/api/v1/submit

header : 
    {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',       u'Authorization': u'Bearer Q7opsQbQ2ZJBruwC1zZATlLi-Fc'}

body looks like
        sr=dev_playspace&kind=self&text=test+text&title=test+playspace

method : POST

Reddit api is responding with

{
    "error": 404, 
    "message": "Not Found"
  }

this is pretty confusing message. the subreddit is there (test subreddit /r/dev_playspace ) , and it seems like I am sending correct payload and url

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Hard to tell what your issue is.

Comment: ok I am adding more details

basically reddit api is responding with {error : 404 , message: "not found"}

Comment: Are you sure the url is right? and are you encoding `data=body` as proper json?

Comment: I followed reddit's  documentation. I have also implemented this request in javascript(react native) . However I am keep getting stuck in python . 
https://www.reddit.com/dev/api/#POST_api_submit

Comment: can you try before `response` add `body = json.dumps(body)`? I wonder if it's how you are sending it. The headers don't seem right to me.

Answer (score 0):

I'm the author of Flask-OAuthlib. It is suggested that you use [Authlib](https://github.com/lepture/authlib) instead. There is a loginpass library which contains the implementation of reddit.

- https://github.com/authlib/loginpass/blob/master/loginpass/reddit.py